# use code inspections in PHPstorm to review a branch or pull request

Tags: code, phpstorm, review

If I checkout a branch from VCS I would like to run inspections on all the changes that the branch has made from (for example) master branch.

Is this possible?

---

I currently have to:

- open all files that I know have been changed in the branch.
- Run inspections on open files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality directly in PhpStorm, but you may try the following workaround:

- `git checkout master`
- `git merge --no-commit <branch>`
- now you have all the difference between your branch and master as uncommitted local changes.
- Invoke "Inspect Code"
- Select "Uncommitted Changes: All"
- `git commit` # commit the merge if needed (or just reset all if you don't need to merge now)

Comment: Inspect Code does not seem to have 'uncomitted changes' ?